# 'Cannot GET error' after refreshing page with html5mode

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-ui-router

This error started showing herself after I added `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` to my state config on AngularJS:

> 'Cannot GET error' after refreshing page with html5mode

I`ve searched for it and found this fix to server side but it doesn't work either because of some JSON errors:( Maybe someone know how to properly fix it witout making new errors?)

```
 app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
 });
```

Comment: Could you show use at least one error which occurs?

Comment: 'Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0' this error shows up when i add res.sendFIle to back-end site

Comment: Also when I remove html5Mode and res.sendFile all works correct except the #! in the URL..

Comment: It seems that in your JS code, you're somewhere requiring a JSON file, and the browser isn't able to correctly receive it from the server. Can you check again?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to the below:

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname + '/public/index.html' });
});
```

Comment: I cannot,It`s a bit big application to paste.

Comment: Can it be because of this error? Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive.
It happends when I remove res.sendFile and refresh the page

Comment: I think permissions problem. Try checking permissions of the public directory.

Comment: But the strangest thing is when I delete html5mode all start to work fully correct.I wouldnt like to change anything but #! in URL is a bit ugly

Comment: I think without having a look at your code it will be difficult to suggest you a solution.